# How to comment for ReSharper so Intellisense displays documentation?

Tags: javascript, documentation, resharper

I want to see my methods' documentation when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> on a method name while coding.

How should I format comments in my JavaScript methods and classes for re#er?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper 6](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/resharper-6/) added support for JavaScript, CSS and HTML. ReSharper is using the same XML documentation annotations that are driving the JavaScript IntelliSense in Visual Studio. The XML format is an extension of the format that C# and VB.NET are using so it should look familiar to .NET developers. The main differences are the additional attributes that have been added to convey the (optional) type information that is not provided by the language itself and the place where those comments are written.

For more information take a look at these pages:

- [The format for JavaScript doc comments](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx)
- [VS 2008 JavaScript Intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx)
- [AjaxDoc: Generates documentation for JavaScript script libraries](http://ajaxdoc.codeplex.com/)